# android trasparent menu icon, ics ads shadow

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a trasparent icon for my application. On Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 with ICS 4.0.4
the problem is android adds a "shadow" when i'm in the application menu, see img:
[image: asdasdasd]

However on the frontpage of the launcher it shows ok, see img:
[image]

It doesn't show in the emulator, but for example google currents app shows ok in both places with no shadow, so what am i doing wrong ? I looked at the logo of google currents a 72x72pixel 72dpi and 32bit trasparent png, did the same thing with Gimp, didn't work